# mdl-switch not working inside mdl-grid & mdl-card

Tags: material-design, material-design-lite

I am trying to put an mdl-switch inside an mdl-card which sits inside an mdl-grid.
the mdl-switch works fine if placed outside the card but just appears as a checkbox inside the card.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes.html">
<h4 class="mdl-typography--display-1 pageTitle">asdf</h4>
<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div ng-repeat="a in b" class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
        <div class="status-card mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp  status-green">
            <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
                <h4 style="width: 100%">    
                    <label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="BSL">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="BSL" class="mdl-switch__input" ng-model="a.asdfChk" />
                        <span class="mdl-switch__label">                                                                                      
                            <small>ASDF</small>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </h4>
            </div>                   
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on Stackoverflow ! Can you share the code of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the post with the document.

Comment: I think it working inside the card. Can you be more brief..

Comment: ok so the problem seems to be the ng-repeat. 

 <div ng-repeat="env in environments">
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-{{$index + 1}}">
  <input type="checkbox" id="switch-{{$index + 1}}" class="mdl-switch__input" checked>
  <span class="mdl-switch__label"></span>
</div>

Comment: does this work after making id dynamic with $index